# Need explanation of round robin scheduling for a problem?

Tags: operating-system

```
     A              50                   1
     B              20                   2
     C              30                   3
     ProcessId      Time                 Order
```

Given the process information table above using Round Robin, what is the average wait time? Assume that time quanta is very small (0.5 s)?

Apparently the answer is 43seconds. I don't understand how that can be. Can I get some help?

I am expecting P2 to finish first and it has waiting time of (40 quanta for A  + 39 quantas for C ) = 79 quantas = 39.5 seconds.

I am expecting P3 to finish second and it has waiting time of (80 quanta for A + 40 quanta for B)  = 120 quantas = 60 seconds.

I am expecting P1 to finish last and it has waiting time of (40 quanta for B + 80 quanta for C) = 120 quantas = 60 seconds.

Averagings = (39.5 + 60 + 60) / 3 = 53.2 seconds. However, the answer seems to be 43seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the process table would look like:

```
 A              100                  1
 B              40                   2
 C              60                   3
 ProcessId      Quanta               Order
```

For the first 40*3=120 quanta there will be 3 processes running. Process B will finish 1 quanta sooner (after 119 quanta), and if it took 119 quanta to get 40 quanta it must've been waiting for 79 quanta.

After the first 120 quanta; the process table would look like:

```
 A              60                   1
 C              20                   3
 ProcessId      Quanta               Order
```

For the next 20*2=40 quanta there will be 2 processes running. Process C will finish after 120+40 quanta, and if it took 160 quanta to get 60 quanta it must've been waiting for 100 quanta.

After the first 160 quanta; the process table would look like:

```
 A              40                   1
 ProcessId      Quanta               Order
```

For the next 40*1=40 quanta there will be 1 process running. Process A will finish after 120+40+40 quanta, and if it took 200 quanta to get 100 quanta it must've been waiting for 100 quanta. An alternative way to calculate this is to say that A must have waited for however many quanta B and C consumed, which is 40+60 = 100 quanta.

Average wait time is (79+100+100)/3 = 93 quanta = 46.5 seconds.